# Input do tipo NUMBER não considera o maxlength

Tags: angularjs, html5

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```html
<input ng-model="idade" type="number" maxlength="3" placeholder="Informe a idade">
```

Quando eu vou testar, o `input` ignora o `maxlength` e permite digitar quantos caracteres eu quiser. Estranhamente, quando eu mudo o type para `tel` ele funciona.

Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver???

Comment: tenta 'ng-maxlength'

Comment: Qual é o objetivo, que tamanho do valor seja igual a 3 digitos (999) ou que o valor máximo seja 3? Tipo number não irá colocar uma máscara em keydown no elemento - se quer limitar que a máxima entrada seja 999, por exemplo, terá que usar uma função.

Comment: já tinha tentado, e não havia dado certo.....
Mudei pra type tel mesmo e deu certo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-maxlength), você só pode utilizar o `maxlength` para
os tipos  **text, email, search, password, tel, ou url**.

Essa foi uma decisão de design.

Caso deseje, você pode utilizar [os atributos min e max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-max) para validar números. (lembrando que essa validação, por padrão, será realizada no submit e não no momento de digitar).

Comment: Então pra eu fazer isso, eu vou ter que utilizar o jquery, correto?
Já que o min e max não atendem as minhas exigências...

Comment: @fernandoocf jQuery é uma opção, mas não a única. O que utilizar fica a seu critério, pois você conhece o seu sistema melhor que nós :p.

Comment: O critério é o mesmo do maxlength.... só permitir que o usuário só digite até 3 caracteres no campo, sem pode passar disso....

Comment: Mudei pra type="tel" e resolveu o meu problema =)

Comment: @fernandoocf Tabém é uma solução. Como eu disse, somente você sabe o que é melhor para você :p

Answer (score 3):

Você pode incluir uma "máscara" no evento `keydown` do `input`. Algo como:

```js
document.getElementById("numero").addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

  if (this.value.length == 3 && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

});

function soNumeros(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if (evt.keyCode)
    return true;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="numero" ng-model="idade" type="number" maxlength="3" placeholder="Informe a idade" onkeypress='soNumeros(event)'>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar o próprio [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) para criar uma [`directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive('ngMax', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element(element).on("keypress keydown", function(e) 
    { 
      if (e.keyCode != 8 && this.value.length == attrs.ngMax) 
      {  
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
    });
  };
});

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input ng-model="idade" 
         type="number"
         ng-maxlength="3" 
         ng-max="3" />
</div>
```

Foi criado a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) `ngMax` que pode ser utilizado com a configuração da quantidade máxima de números.

Comment: Legal a diretiva, mas se eu errar a idade tenho que dar um refresh na página pra corrigi-la?

Comment: @DiegoAugusto eu coloquei `ng-maxlength` que tem um caracter de validação e a `directive` criada para fazer o papel de uma mascara. Não... claro depende do seu contexto, mas, não...

Comment: Entendi, é que nesse exemplo o backspace não funciona rs

Comment: @DiegoAugusto é número!? não é? (**pela lógica número não tem espaço, só se sua regra for outra**)

Comment: Sim, acho que você não entendeu. Se eu digitar uma idade x e tentar apagar pra digitar outra idade o input fica bloqueado, no caso eu teria que dar um refresh na página pra digitar outra idade.

Comment: Se eu quiser editar a mesma também só após um refresh

Comment: @DiegoAugusto acabei de testar no exemplo da resposta e funciona o `backspace` (desculpe anteriormente não tinha entendido, exemplo feito para html5 e angular igual suas tags, tem outro proposito?), mas, reforçando funciona.

Comment: É problema do navegador, no Firefox não funciona

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50725/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-diegoaugusto).

Comment: @DiegoAugusto fiz os ajustes ... agora está dentro dos conforme

Answer (score 0):

A diretiva poderia ser melhorada permitindo que se navegue dentro do campo e também se possa apagar de qualquer posição.

```
app.directive('ngMax', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element(element).on("keypress keydown", function(e) { 
            if (e.keyCode != 8 &&
                e.keyCode != 9 &&
                e.keyCode != 35 &&
                e.keyCode != 36 &&
                e.keyCode != 37 &&
                e.keyCode != 39 &&
                e.keyCode != 46 &&
                this.value.length == attrs.ngMax
            ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
});
```