# Impedir digitar letras no input com angular

Tags: angularjs

como impedir que seja digitada letras em um `input` onde deve ser apenas digitado números com angular? Apenas com diretivas é possível?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173490/input-do-tipo-number-n%C3%A3o-considera-o-maxlength/173492

Comment: Não serve usar o `type=number`?

Comment: no doc so achei isso https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: Por que não usa a propriedade "type" do html?

Comment: @LINQ Se você também precisa dar suporte a versões de browsers que não suportam a especificação de `type`, ou implementam parcialmente, sim.

Comment: Então, @OnoSendai. Justamente por isso que perguntei antes de escrever como resposta =D Aliás, bueníssima resposta

Comment: @LINQ *Why, thank you kind sir.*

Answer (score 3):

Utilize uma diretiva que remova todos os caracteres não-numéricos.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('numerosApenas', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
    
      function parserNumerico(textoOriginal) {
      
        // Troque tudo o que não for um dígito válido por uma string vazia
        var inputSemNumeros = textoOriginal.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
        if(inputSemNumeros !== textoOriginal) {
        
            // reverta o valor para a versão sem números.
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(inputSemNumeros);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return Number(inputSemNumeros);
      }
      
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(parserNumerico);
    }
  }; 
})

.controller('myController', function($scope){

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <input type='text' numeros-apenas ng-model='valor' />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556249/1845714)